# Can't get SSL site to load JS + CSS properly. Throwing 409 (conflict)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, nginx

I am using `nginx` with `codeigniter` to serve my site.
When there is no proxy I am able to load ssl site properly.

But when a computer behind a proxy tries to access it, there's a `409` conflict.

It is able to load the non-ssl site properly behind the proxy.

Here is the ssl code-block in the nginx conf:

[Pastie Nginx Conf](http://pastie.org/9600466)

### What's weird is when I'm directly opening the css or js file (e.g. typing the css url in the browser), it will load it properly.

Here are the response + request headers of an asset that's returning `409` Conflict.

Request Headers:

```
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ci_session=ca41f4c9930b678f07acb9a45c839b63
Host:www.mywebsite.com
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 24 Sep 2014 01:13:00 GMT
If-None-Match:"54221a9c-1da51"
Referer:https://www.mywebsite.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Length:1256
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:close
```

---

When browsing in FF it throws this:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.mywebsite.com. Certificate type not approved for application. (Error code: sec_error_inadequate_cert_type)
```

Serving static assets did not work..

Answer (score 1):

Both, nginx documentation and w3 documentation possibly allow you to understand better the issue. Seems that the problem could be associated to a conflict when passing the request across the proxy. Which means the proxy is changing requests parameters. Without looking and comparing the logs from both requests is difficult to tell where is the difference.

Have a look to these links:

http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-ssl-termination/

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Make also sure your CSS and JS requests may vary in terms of cache, so again, the proxy may be keeping the requests as they are.

Comment: Yeah I'm suspecting it might be related to the timeout / cache..  It will load some css files while not others, and in incognito mode it will load the other files and not the others, so it's very inconsistent.  Will keep you updated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The caching doesn't seem to be the problem because it doesn't look like you're setting a cache at all. To set the cache you need something like:
        location ~* .(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

If you look at the [sample CI config](http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter) on the nginx wiki, then you'll see that it differs quite a bit.

It could also be a problem with your `$config['base_url']` setting in CI. Again, more info on the same nginx wiki page.

---

Updated response:

First, you might be able to get some more information if you put the logs in the block:

```
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebserver.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebserver.com_error.log;
```

Or change the paths to whatever you'd like.

But, it looks like we might be dealing with two different errors between the `409` and the `sec_error_inadequate_cert_type`.

### 409 Error

So, let's look at the possible causes of the 409 error first:

The 409 error could come from many different places, but here's a quick statement about what it means:

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.

Strangely, this happens often with PUT requests (here think of it as an EDIT CONFLICT). So, one problem might be that the request is making CI is rewrite these files, thus causing the 409. You can also find this error often with Web Dav, which makes sense.

It also could be linked to the keep-alive part in that it might be generating the assets differently because of that and is thus asking for an older version of the asset when a new one is written. You might be able to fix
that by adding `keepalive_timeout 75 75;` to the server block. It might also be related to the Connection/Proxy-Connection headers. Here is [some more reading](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-proxy-connection-header.html) on the `Connection` and the `Proxy-Connection` headers.

There might be a problem with the proxy in rewriting the regular request. It's better to use:
`return 301 $scheme:/$server_name$request_uri;` for several reasons some of which are related to SEO, 
but it *could* also be losing the some security information during the proxy pass.

### sec_error_inadequate_cert_type

So, FF has a history of throwing this error (based on bug reports) when some other browsers don't. Does it do the same sort of thing with Chrome?

The sec_error_inadequate_cert_type code could also indicate many different things:

Do the static assets happen to be served on a sub-domain that the SSL Cert doesn't cover? Also, you might want to indicate the particular `ssl_protocols` and the `ssl_ciphers` in the server block.

These might not apply:
        ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

There are some other possibilities that I've investigated, and I've included them in a sample nginx config below that has some more directives that might help out, so see if the conf below might work.

If you find some stuff in the error logs after implementing them or if there is different information that comes from another browser, then update me.

```
    server{
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mywebserver.com;
        return 301 $scheme:/$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen                          443 ssl;
        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate                 /etc/nginx/ssl/www.mysite.com.SSL.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key             /etc/nginx/ssl/www.mysite.com.key;

        server_name                     www.mysite.com;
        index                           index.php;
        root                            /home/user/workspace/;

        ## Access and error logs.
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebserver.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebserver.com_error.log;

        ## Keep alive timeout set to a greater value for SSL/TLS.
        keepalive_timeout               75 75;

        ## Strict Transport Security header for enhanced security. See
        ## http://www.chromium.org/sts.
        add_header                      Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info     ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass                unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index               index.php;
            fastcgi_param               SCRIPT_FILENAME    /usr/home/user/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include                     fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* .(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
            gzip_static                 on;

            expires                     max;
            add_header                  ETag '';
            add_header                  Last-Modified '';
            add_header                  Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, no-transform, public";
            add_header                  Accept-Ranges '';

            tcp_nodelay                 off;
            log_not_found               off;

            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache             max=3000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid       45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses    2;
            open_file_cache_errors      off;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updating the base url, index_page and uri_protocol did not resolve it.

Comment: Sure, it rewrites it to use ssl though http://pastie.org/9618581  Just to reiterate, ssl runs fine on my computer when it's not behind the proxy.

Comment: This is a really, really strange problem. I've updated my answer to see if anything else works. More than likely, however, the proxy is stripping some of the headers that are necessary in order to make it work. And it might be changing the nature of the requests. Explicitly adding headers and changing the keep-alive might help out. Let me know.